# Google App Engine — Allow customers to connect their domain to my website builder app

Tags: virtualhost, domain, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have a website builder on GAE which is successfully connected to my domain (`example.com`). A customer designs a website and connect it to his domain (`customer.com`). From programming side everything is alright (i.e. if `customer.com` hits my web application, the correct website displays).

But the problem is that GAE doesn't support static IP and I don't know how customers can set a `DNS A record` to point their domain to my application. Even CNAME doesn't work (i.e. `landing.customer.com CNAME example.com` outputs google's 404 error page).

So any solution for such a scenario?

Comment: The CNAME is the solution.

Comment: @womble - That is correct if the domain is verified by Google and the domain name is added to App Engine. Only specifying a CNAME will not work as the GFE (Google Frontend) will not know about the custom domain name mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the domain name as a verified domain and add the domain name to App Engine.

This article covers the steps in detail:

[Mapping Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains)

If you skip the steps in the article and only add the A and CNAME records, the Google Frontend (GFE) will not know about the custom domain name mapping. The GFE uses the HTTP Host header to map domain names to App Engine services.

App Engine does support A and AAAA DNS resource records so that you can map the root domain to App Engine (example.com) and CNAME for subdomains (www.example.com).

Comment: The problem is that I want this process to be automatic or from DNS configuration as I can't repeat that process for 1000 domains (customers) who wants to link their domain to their website.

Comment: Your requirement does not change my answer. You can write your own software using Google APIs to do most of it. The validation of domain ownership must be done in the console. Therefore, your requirements are not supported by Google Cloud App Engine for custom domain mapping. Once you have verified domain ownership, you can do everything else via APIs.